# knockout mapping and current item properties

Tags: knockout.js

When I am creating the view model using ko.mapping I extend it with some extra observables. Binding, it works perfectly in the view but when I try to click the button and get data, extended properties don't appear. Why?

```
  create: function (options) {
    var parent = new Parent(options.data);
    parent.id = 1;
    parent.fullName = ko.computed(function () {
        return parent.firstName() + " " + parent.lastName();
    });
    parent.select = function (data, event) {
        console.log(ko.mapping.toJSON(data));
    };
    return parent;
  }
```

Full code:
http://jsfiddle.net/rferreiraperez/9v2hy/

Observable property ID and FULLNAME don't appear in console.
Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Thanks for your answers,
I think I've found the best solution for the problem. In Knockout API documentation you can see solution.
Including certain properties using “include”: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html
I have just updated the previous code:
http://jsfiddle.net/rferreiraperez/9v2hy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add fullName filed in data object.

It's define in "data" object after lastName: "Smith" filed at line no.6.

Please refer

```
Visit http://jsfiddle.net/nikunjbbalar/4FwQg/2/
```

Thanks,
Nikunj Balar.

Answer (score 1):

I think `ko.mapping.toJSON` only shows the properties it has mapped itself.

If you try:

```
console.log(ko.toJSON(data));
```

You'll see `fullName` at the end (and `id`) at the beginning.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GabrielTran/9v2hy/4/)**